# No unique mode; found 2 equally common values

Tags: python, statistics

I'm using `statistics.mode([1, 1, 2, 2, 3])` to find the mode, but I get:

> no unique mode; found 2 equally common values

When more than one mode is found, how can I output either `1` or `2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
lst = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]

# test for count lst elements
lst_count = [[x, lst.count(x)] for x in set(lst)]
print lst_count
# [[1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 1]]

# remove count <= 1
lst_count = [x for x in set(lst) if lst.count(x) > 1]
print lst_count
# [1, 2]

# get 1 or 2 by index
print lst_count[0], lst_count[1]
# 1 2
```

Another way:

```
from collections import Counter

# change lst elements to str, for more readable
lst = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']

# get a dict, key is the elements in lst, value is count of the element
d_mem_count = Counter(lst)
print d_mem_count
# Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 1})

for k in d_mem_count.keys():
    if d_mem_count[k] > 1:
        print k

# output as below
# a
# b
```

Answer (score 11):

Note that in `Python 3.8` the behaviour of [`statistics.mode`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/statistics.html?highlight=mode#statistics.mode) has changed:

> Changed in version 3.8: Now handles multimodal datasets by returning the first mode encountered. Formerly, it raised StatisticsError when more than one mode was found.

In your example:

```
from statistics import mode

mode([1, 1, 2, 2, 3])
# 1
```

---

Also starting in `Python 3.8`, you can alternatively use [`statistics.multimode`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/statistics.html?highlight=mode#statistics.multimode) to return the list of the most frequently occurring values in the order they were first encountered:

```
from statistics import multimode

multimode([1, 1, 2, 2, 3])
# [1, 2]
```

Comment: That's slick, and happened to be just what I needed in my pandas groupby agg call

Answer (score 7):

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter([1,1,2,2,3])
c.most_common(1)
# output
>>> [(1,2)] #the key 1, 2 occurrences.
```

From the docs:

> "most_common([n]): Returns a list of the n most common elements and
>   their counts from the most common to the least. Elements with equal
>   counts are ordered arbitrarily"

Answer (score 6):

```
from scipy import stats as s
a=[1,1,2,2,3]
print(int(s.mode(a)[0]))
```

Comment: This answer was automatically tagged "low quality". As explained in the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) ("Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."), please edit your answer to tell the OP what he's doing wrong, how you reasoned and what your code is about, to show that you understood the question and to make benefit both the OP and future visitors.

Answer (score 5):

Try this to find the max values as mode when no unique mode:

```
max([p[0] for p in statistics._counts([1, 1, 2, 2, 3])])
```

Comment: This is the real answer.  Clearly the OP wasn't on Python 3.8 when asking since that error doesn't appear on that version and later, so this proxies the appropriate behavior and keeps it all to one tidy function with the same dependency.

Answer (score 3):

Try this function, which finds the max values as mode when no unique mode:

```
import statistics
def find_max_mode(list1):
    list_table = statistics._counts(list1)
    len_table = len(list_table)

    if len_table == 1:
        max_mode = statistics.mode(list1)
    else:
        new_list = []
        for i in range(len_table):
            new_list.append(list_table[i][0])
        max_mode = max(new_list) # use the max value here
    return max_mode

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = [1,1,2,2,3]
    print(find_max_mode(a)) # print 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def MultiModeCalc(data):
    """
    set(data) -> discards duplicated values

    list(map(lambda x: data.count(x), set(data))))) -> counting how many of 
    each value there are

    dict(zip(set(data), list(map(lambda x: data.count(x), set(data))))) -> 
    making a dictionary by zipping all unique values(as keys) with their 
    frequency in the data(as values)

    return [i for i in multimode if multimode[i] == max(multimode.values())] 
    -> returning a list of the values that are most frequent in the data 
    """
    multimode = dict(zip(set(data), list(map(lambda x: data.count(x), set(data)))))
    return [i for i in multimode if multimode[i] == max(multimode.values())]
dataset = [1,2,5,6,3,7,2,3,9,1,10,3,1,2,9,9]
print(MultiModeCalc(dataset))
# [1, 2, 3, 9]
```

A **DRY** answer.

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I just faced the same issue. This how I solved it pretty simply:

```
def most_element(liste):
    numeral=[[liste.count(nb), nb] for nb in liste]
    numeral.sort(key=lambda x:x[0], reverse=True)
    return(numeral[0][1])
```

Not sure this the most elegant way but it does the job :). Hope it will help